# mysqli_data_seek Function Returns Username Result, When Username Not in Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a function in which if a named user is in my database, I'll have a message on my screen of a string value, that simply says my function works.

However, when I change the name to one that doesn't exist in the database, I still get a string output that says the function works. So I am trying to figure out where my logic is messed in the query. Here's what I have:

**Users.php File:**

```
<?php

function user_exists($username)
{
    $db = "adults";
    $dbH = "localhost";
    $dbU = "root";
    $dbP = "Jeffery9";

    //connection to database
    $dbCon =  mysqli_connect($dbH, $dbU, $dbP, $db);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    // $query = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return (mysqli_data_seek(mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users`   WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

?>
```

Now here's the login page which processes the function to see if a user actually exists:

**Login.php File:**

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (user_exists('raiders7') === true)
{
    echo 'user found!';
}
die();

if(empty($_POST) === false)
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true)
    {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password.';   
    }
    else if (user_exists($username) === false)
    {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
    }
}
?>
```

Of course I have one row and one user in the database. When the string is `user_exists('raiders7')`, I get `user found!` on my index page.

But when it's `user_exists('something else')` it still returns `user found!` on the page.

How is this so? The page should be blank if the user doesn't exist.

Lastly, I'm using another function to sanitize my data like such:

**General.php File:**

```
<?php

function sanitize($data)
{
    $db = "adults";
    $dbH = "localhost";
    $dbU = "root";
    $dbP = "Jeffery9";

    // connection to database
    $dbCon =  mysqli_connect($dbH, $dbU, $dbP, $db);

    return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbCon, $data);
}

?>
```

Don't know if the last part is helpful, but can someone kindly help me fix my logic on how I can stop getting a `user found!` message, when the user doesn't exist in my test database. Thank you.

Comment: You can cut a lot of your code down to just simply using `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fetch the results to get the correct/desired result.

What happens is you just move the pointer then of course there will always be a result set row in index 0

```
+----------------+
| COUNT(user_id) | // even when count is zero, your condition will still be true
+----------------+
| 0              |
+----------------+
```

Even when the username is wrong/does not exist!

Fetch the result properly then check the count

```
$username = $dbCon->real_escape_string($username);
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as total FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$count = $row['total']; // fetch the result!

if($count > 0) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Or as @Fred said, just use `num_rows` and much better to bind it:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?';
$select = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
$select->bind_param('s', $username);
$select->execute();

if($select->num_rows > 0) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: The other thing I would have pointed out here is that separating the SQL out into its own variable would be helpful too (so you could echo out the statement (or even log it to error_log) that you're about to execute).  $sql = "SELECT COUNT... WHERE `username` = '$username";

Comment: *"Much better to bind it:"* - Much ;)

Comment: @JonathonHibbard yes could also be helpful when debugging query, so you'll know what to expect.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah feels much right using it. doesn't make sense in OP having its own wrapper of escaping input. bind it and then no need for that function.

Comment: It's all about "safe streamlining" ;) short & strong.

Comment: *Hm...* - no green ticky yet.

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe still busy with something, theres even a rare case where i got my answer accepted after a month lol.

Comment: *Ah*, there's that too. I know what you mean; I once got an accepted answer after 6 months (believe it or not), I was baffled and glad all at the same while. lol

Comment: Sorry, guys... I'm just now getting back to the solution and have not tried it; thus no ticky green! Lol. I see the reference for the escape string deal... so am I running this in my `users.php` in place of everything from `$username = sanitize` on down? I could use placement here! :)

Comment: Thanks fellas! It works. I edited a tiny portion and got my desired results. The bind thing still throws me off though, but I'll have to really study around with it. Believe it or not, I just picked up a PHP tutorial about a day ago! My preferred is vb.net/asp.net & c#... I'm sorta being forced to learn PHP/Mysql, after a college professor ditched our class in mid year to cash in his pension. Yeah!!! I failed that class, and now here I am, trying to reedem myself.

Comment: `Another happy ending` - @DesignerMind glad it worked out ;) you're welcome.

Comment: @DesignerMind no worries not in a hurry to be accepted anyways :). yes a better replacement would be to prepare your statements. if you already know c# then PHP will be just easy pickin's for you lol. i'm sure you'll get a hang of it real soon. theres no shortage of resources anyways. im glad this helped